# Library name and function name obfuscation

Tags: c, assembly, disassembly

I have c code that contains string constants, a library import via #pragma comment(lib, "urlmon.lib") and #includes. My task is to obfuscate all strings, imported library names and associated functions so that they cannot easily be seen within a debugger, say OllyDbg etc. 
I have a clue about the strings, but the obfuscation of library and function names gives me a headache.

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "urlmon.lib")

int main(void)
{
    int op1, op2, n;
    HRESULT res;

    printf("some string- Version 0xC0DEDBAD\n");
    printf("some string:\n");
    printf("1) some string\n");
    printf("2) some string\n");
    printf("3) some string\n");
    printf("4) some string \n");

    scanf("%d", &n);

    switch(n)
    {
        case 1:
        case 2:
            printf("enter number:\n");
            scanf("%d", &op1);

            printf("Bitte geben Sie die zweite Zahl ein:\n");
            scanf("%d", &op2);

            if(n == 1)
                printf("some string\n", op1, op2, op1 + op2);
            else
                printf("some string", op1, op2, op1 - op2);

            break;
        case 3:
            res = URLDownloadToFile(0, TEXT("url"), TEXT("C:\xyz.exe"), 0, 0);

            if(res == S_OK)
                printf("some string.\n");
            else
                printf("some string.\n");

            break;
        case 4:
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the question? For symbols related to functions in external libraries, you cannot obfuscate them. You might obfuscate your own defined symbols.

Comment: Not sure I get you. If you strip the objects and don't give out the debugging information then those non-string items you mentioned will not be visible to a debugger. Or do you actually want to obfuscate the source code itself?

Comment: If the user isn't tech-savy, you don't need to obfuscate them. If they are, it doesn't matter. Either way, it's a complete waste of time and makes the code more difficult to maintain for no benefit.

Comment: What about explicitly using `LoadLibrary` to grab the DLLs you need. It's a trivial exercise to obfuscate the library names, unscrambling them immediately before loading them. Same goes for the functions you need inside them. If you cant load the functions by ordinal number, you can simply grab them by their name. You'd need to use `LoadLibrary`, `GetProcAddress` and for your example above, you'd be after either `URLDownloadToFileA` or `URLDownloadToFileW`

Comment: Sorry for my unprecise explanation. The missing link is that a reverse engineer has only access to the binary and not the c code. The resulting binary from the code above shall impede the analysis.

Comment: by obfuscating as much as possible

Comment: What about a [scrambler](https://code.google.com/p/pescrambler/)? Remember: As @mike noted, trying to prevent reverse engineering is futile. Most scramblers are vulnerable to an easy dump and the rest to a slightly more sophisticated one. Also note that in C strings works very differently from, say C#. C strings are emitted in a read-only section, loaded at once and used through pointers. Very fast. In order to de-scramble them it's necessary to allocate memory at runtime and access them through pointers from the de-scrambling routine (and this is still very easy to crack).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to obfuscate the used libraries it is useful to load them at runtime. So it cannot directly be seen which libraries are used. Furthermore strings containg library names can be obfuscated to impede the analysis.